# Python map and lambda combination gives error

Tags: python, lambda, pyvmomi

I am trying the following working code

```
from pyVmomi import vim
mapping = []
propertyDict = {'ipv4': '192.168.2.2/24'}
```

> ```
> for k in propertyDict:
>     v = propertyDict[k]
>     mapping.append(vim.KeyValue(key=k, value=v))
> ```

with **map** and **lambda** as below

```
mapping.append(map(lambda k: vim.KeyValue(key=k,value=propertyDict[k]), propertyDict))
```

but getting error as ***For "propertyMapping" expected type vim.KeyValue, but got list***, when I used it in **mapping** value in the following function

```
if mapping:
    spec_params = vim.OvfManager.CreateImportSpecParams(entityName=vmname,
                                                         propertyMapping=mapping)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` function returns an iterator with several values, and not a single value.

You should replace:

```
mapping.append(map(lambda k: vim.KeyValue(key=k,value=propertyDict[k]), propertyDict))
```

by:

```
mapping.extend(map(lambda k: vim.KeyValue(key=k,value=propertyDict[k]), propertyDict))
```

Moreover, `map` is rarely used in python. We prefer list comprehensions.
I would propose:

```
mapping.extend(vim.KeyValue(key=k, value=v) for k,v in propertyDict.items())
```

Comment: There is nothing terribly wrong with `map` in the right place (where you already have an existing, ideally built-in, function that does exactly what you need). But if you need a `lambda` to use `map`, yes, you should be using a list comprehension (eager, like Py2 `map`) or generator expression (lazy, like Py3 `map`).